# Viewing DB Results in Laravel

Tags: database, variables, laravel-5, undefined

I am working on a Laravel Project and I keep getting undefined variable when I try to output the DB to a blade template. The DB is seeded with dummy data. When a user logs in it should redirect to the enquiries blade which will then display the data from the db

```
 <?php

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('home', function (){
return View::make('home');
});


Route::get('example', function(){
return View::make('example');
});

 Route::get('enquiries', function (){
 return View::make('enquiries');
 });

  Route::get('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@showLogin'));

 // route to process the form
 /*Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin'));*/


 /*Route::get('admin', function () {
 //brings Auth method into action
 })->middleware('auth');*/




 Auth::routes();

 Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('welcome');

 Auth::routes();

 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

This is the blade template code

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')
<div class="container" id="database" name="database">
    <div class="row white">
        <br>
        <h1 class="centered">Customer Enquiries</h1>
        <hr>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h3>Customer Table</h3>
                 @foreach ( $customer as $customer)

                <!--Display customers table-->
                <h2>{{ $customer->custID }} <small>{{ $customer->name }}: {{ $customer->number }}:{{ $customer->email }}: {{ $customer->comments }}:{{ $customer->bookingID }}</small></h2>
                @endforeach

                <!-- Display bookings table -->
                <h3>Booking Table</h3>
                @foreach ($bookings as $booking)
                    <p>{{ $booking->bookingID }}:{{ $booking->custID }}:{{ $booking->productID }}</p>
                @endforeach

                <!-- Display Products table -->
                <h3>Products Table</h3>
                @foreach($products as $product)
                <p>{{ $product->productID }}:{{ $product->name }}:{{ $product->description }}</p>
                @endforeach
        </div><!-- col-lg-6 -->
<!-- col-lg-6 -->
    </div><!-- row -->
</div>
@endsection
```

Ive looked through lots of different posts and it seems simple enough to get the data to display but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: can you provide a controller code?